# Creation of Enterprise level Common UI Solution in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for creating common UI solution in ASP.net, which consists of all CSS and Jquery. 
Intention is to use this solution to all CSS/Jquery related development and refer this in all the other MVC application so that style is consistent across all the product.

Is this possible? could you please suggest

Comment: In one MVC project or more than one MVC project, you wanna add CSS and jQuery ?

Comment: In shared layout(master page) can attach all the css and js that can allpy to all the child layouts(pages) .for the examples folow the links https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/layout-view-in-asp.net-mvc                                          https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-page-layouts-with-view-master-pages-cs

Comment: Its like i have multiple MVC application in different solution. I would like maintain  common styles in  all of  them. And create UI framework application, changes to this application should apply to all the other applications.